# After returning from standby mode, Windows 7 asks for login twice

Tags: windows-7, login, standby

When a Windows 7 32-bit PC attached to a domain comes back from standby mode and has no user logged in, if I log in once, it jumps back to the login screen. If I log in for a second time, then it actually logs in.

This happens on multiple PCs, and is not a hardware issue. The PCs are also free of viruses/malware, and are otherwise Problem-free.

Why does it do this, and is there a way to prevent this annoyance?

Comment: I've seen this once before but haven't been able to figure it out either

Comment: I've seen this as well. It started happening on my family's desktop, and drives them nuts. (This is on a computer not on a domain, but otherwise same problem. So cached credentials as suggested below can't be it.) I spent hours looking into it, never figured anything out. I'd love to know what solutions people can think up. I may even return to post a bounty...

Comment: @Brenton and @ForceFlow, I finally figured it out! There is a KB article for the problem, and a hotfix released. See my answer below for details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out that this is a known issue.

> **KB2345131: The logon screen appears two times when you resume Windows 7 from Sleep or Hibernation**
>
> The logon screen may appear two times. Therefore, you have to enter your credentials two times.
>
> This issue occurs when there are multiple pending lock signals to be processed when the user is logging in. In this situation, the WinLogon state machine logs the user off.

Microsoft has released a preliminary hotfix. Because it is only preliminary, and most installations do not experience this problem, the hotfix has not been released in the normal automatic updates channel, which is why the problem hasn't been fixed automatically 
yet. You can [download the hotfix from Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;2345131) and install it manually.

I installed the hotfix on our computer which was experiencing this issue, and after three days the problem has yet to reappear, so it looks like this fix works.

Comment: Nice find! I wonder when it's going to be rolled out over auto-updates.

Comment: Hard to say. Seems like the sort of thing which may be included with SP1 when it eventually gets released, but who really knows.

Answer (score 0):

Cached credentials are probably meeting some pre-defined rule or policy for timing out, and trying to renegotiate with the domain controller. That's a guess, but I've seen the behaviour before in a similar environment.